# Options corresponding to Smart Fix 100% in Photoshop Elements

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-photoshop-elements

I'd like to know which options I should change manually to get the same result of Smart Fix 100% in Photoshop Elements. I tried to search a correspondence, but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Photoshop Elements user, but from looking at some tutorials on youtube, Smart Fix in Elements appears to be a way to automate Levels, Saturation, and Color Balance adjustments as a one-click-fix, with the addition of a slider to control the level of the adjustments.  The Smart Fix feature appears to be similar to Photoshop CCs Auto Tone, Auto Color, and Auto Contrast functionality.

You may have to experiment to get manual adjustments that are similar to Smart Fix. There's unlikely to be just one set of adjustment values, since Smart Fix appears to be applied based on some kind of analysis of the photograph, which is probably done using some kind of algorithm.

Although Smart Fix will work with most photographs, it will fail with others that perhaps have more extreme lighting conditions.  It's an attempt by Adobe to create a one-click-fix for beginners/novices to photo editing, which works fine most of the time. However, these kind of automated fixes are not so good if you need more creative control of the adjustments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @BillyKerr